# Codeigniter pagination not adding new page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I tried to use the codeigniter pagination library and it doesn't work for me. I'm trying to have 24 products on the all products page and when there's more products it should add a link to the next page. So right now I have more than 24 products on the site and no new page is added.

with this line I'm getting all the products from product table:

```
$data['products'] = $this->Product_model->selectProducts();
```

This is my controller function:

```
  public function pagination() {
        //load pagination library
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        //laad Products_model voor pagination
        $this->load->model('Products_model');
        $this->load->model('Product_model');

        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "AlleCadeausController/pagination";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->products->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 24;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->selectProducts();
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view("allecadeaus", $data);
    }
```

My model (Products_model):

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("products");
    }

    public function fetch_products() {
        $query = $this->db->get("products");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
}

?>
```

This is my view file (I don't know if I need to add anything in the view file for the pagination to work):

```
<?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->
<div class="all-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning header-text" style="font-size:25px;font-weight: bold;">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>


 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->

    <div class="row">
            <div class="menu">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>


 <div class="categorieen">
      <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
  <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="box1"><a class="listcat" href="<?php echo base_url().'Product/category/' . $category->id; ?>"> <?php echo $category->name; ?></a></label>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>                   




                </div>
            </div> 

<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->

<div class="main">
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>

   <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>"> <div class="main-products">

          <img id="cadeaufoto" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product["product_foto_thumb"]; ?>">

        <div class="product_naam"><h3><?php echo $product["product_naam"]; ?></h3></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product["ophaal_plaats"]; ?>
        </div>
        </a>

         <div class="aangeboden_door">     
         <?php 
          //Here is the active record query which is getting the 'voorname' and other data
          $userarray = $this->db->get_Where('users', array('user_id'=>$product["user_id"]))->row_array(); 
          // you can print_r($userarray); for see the array you get
      ?>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/userdetails/'.$product['user_id'];?>">
      <td><?php echo $userarray['voornaam'];?></td>
    </tr> 


        </div> 

</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');?>
```

Comment: A product_model and a products_model? That's going to lead to some fun and games.

Comment: You have created the links - but you are not using them (echo $links ) anywhere in your View. That is usually a good reason something won't show up.

Comment: Yeh but the links are not working when I try to echo it. Can u show me the right code to make the links?

Comment: I kind of have... Well we can look at whats in the $config by var_dump($config) after you've finished setting it up... I am guessing your total_rows might be null

Comment: I did this in my view: <?php   echo '<pre>';
var_dump($config);
echo '</pre>';    ?> and the error is: undefined variable: config

Comment: No, it has to be in your controller. You haven't passed $config into your view so it wont be there...

Comment: I typed var_dump($config); in controller function but noting happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159223/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-learningprogrammingphp44).

Comment: @Learningprogrammingphp44: You are a fresher in php plz follow this link its easy for you https://github.com/soyosolution/CodeIgniter-pagination-library

Comment: thanks ill check it out..

Comment: Tip the controller files and classes should have first letter only upper case wrong Allecadeauscontroller.php  `base_url(allecadeauscontroller/pagination);`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the fine working pagination code, hope it will fix the issue you have.

**Model**

```
public function fetch_oldusers($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get_where('dc_user',array('Is_Hidden'=>0));

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**View**

```
 <div class="text-center"><nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                                            <ul class="pagination">

                                                <li><?php echo $links; ?></li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </nav></div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function Users()
    {
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "master/Users";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->bm->record_countolduser();
        $config['use_page_numbers'] =True;

        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a><b class="text-success">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a>';
        $config["per_page"] =10;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data['title'] = "Users List";
        $data["posts"] = $this->bm->fetch_oldusers($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('Admin/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('Admin/nav');
        $this->load->view('Admin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('Admin/old_user', $data);
        $this->load->view('Admin/footer');
    }
```

It is working fine for me.

Comment: I just dont understand this line: $data["posts"] = $this->bm->fetch_oldusers($config["per_page"], $page);   is it important line?

Comment: And this line in model :         $query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('Is_Hidden'=>0));  what do I put instead of  Is_Hidden ? or do I keep it like that? I did change the table name already

Comment: I have wrote tutorial about Cdeigniter Pagination. Please have a look and give your suggestions https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/